# How do I live search a collection using meteor, and ONLY display matching results?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Im trying to create a search that will filter through a database of items and show matching options below the search input, so the user can select a "valid" option as it were. I am getting the effect of the items being filtered. However, when the search bar is empty it shows all the items in that collection. Is there a way I can prevent this, so it only shows options once a search has begun?

HTML

```xml
<template name="addItem">
<form class="addNewItem">
<input type="text" class="newItem" name="newItem" placeholder=" + new item">
</form>
<ul>&nbsp;
{{> search}}
</ul>
</template>

<template name="search">
  &nbsp;
  {{#if searchResults.results}}
  {{#each searchResults.results}}
      <li>
      {{itemName}}
      </li>
      {{/each}}
      {{/if}}
</template>
```

JS

```js
'keyup input.newItem': function (evt) {
      Session.set('search-query', evt.currentTarget.value);
      var search = Session.get('search-query');
      console.log(search);
    },

});

  Template.search.helpers({
    searchResults: function (){
    var keyword  = Session.get('search-query');
    var query = new RegExp( keyword, 'i' );
    var results = Equipment.find({'itemName': query}, {});
    return {results: results}; 
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `if` block to your template:

```
<template name="addItem">
<form class="addNewItem">
<input type="text" class="newItem" name="newItem" placeholder=" + new item">
</form>
<ul>&nbsp;
{{#if searchInputNotEmpty}}
{{> search}}
{{/if}}
</ul>
</template>
```

And add a `searchInputNotEmpty` helper, to check the `search-query` Session variable you’re already setting:

```
Template.addItem.helpers({
  searchInputNotEmpty: function() {
    var input = Session.get('search-query');
    return input != null && input != '';
  }
});
```